# Get comments that mention your user

Tags: soundcloud

What is the API method that returns your mentions, i.e. when somebody mentions you in a comment? They show up in your notifications in the Soundcloud interface where you can reply to them, but I don't see any way to get them via the API.

Comment: For the private uploads I can't see notifications in the interface too :(